# Forcing a Drag event anywhere in a container element to drag the container instead of the inner element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to implement a drag n drop interface to build out list of 'Products'.

**Each 'Product' has the following HTML:**

```
<div class="pcontainer" data-id="1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">

  <p class="productname">...</p>
  <img class="productimage" href="..."/>

</div>
```

I want to allow users to add the product to a 'wishlist' by dragging from anywhere inside the `productcontainer` div the product and drop it on a target.

**The drop target is as follows:**

```
<div id="droptarget" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  Drop Products Here
</div>
```

I'm implemented a prototype using simple HTML5, and it seems to work well, except that if I click directly on any of the elements inside the div, it doesn't drag correctly.

**Javascript:**

```
function allowDrop(ev)
{
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev)
{
  //get the product id (with jquery)
  var $target = $(ev.target);
  var id = $target.attr('data-id');

  ev.dataTransfer.setData("ID",id);
}

function drop(ev)
{
  ev.preventDefault();
  var id=ev.dataTransfer.getData("ID");

  //do stuff to save product to list using its id
  ...
}
```

I modified this code from [this simple demo at w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop).  **Is there a simple way to make all drags on the inner elements translate to drags on the container element?**

***Or is there all-together better approach to doing this?*** (browser compatibility is a big issue with this html5 approach).  I'm aware that a jQuery draggable library exists but I'm not sure if it is what I really need.

### UPDATE:

Created JSFiddle so you can see what I mean in action: 
[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7mm4R/14/)

If you drag from the padding then it alerts `1`, if you drag from the image it alerts `undefined`

Comment: Can you show a working jsfiddle of your current code and what you can't do with it?

Comment: yea, let me try. The issue is that if you click and drag over any of the inner elements (the <img> or <p> tags) then those elements are dragged when I need to drag to happen on the container div

Comment: Ok. I'm pretty sure the jQuery draggable/droppable module in jquery UI would do exactly what you need (and much more) but I don't see why you couldn't do it in vanilla javascript. Adding a jsfiddle will help others find what's wrong with your code/logic

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7mm4R/11/ if you drag from the container padding it alerts 1, if you drag from the image it alerts undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sooo yea...  The jquery-ui draggable and droppable were exactly what I needed.  See these [demos](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/)